# How to connect a service running inside a docker with consul?

Tags: docker, consul

I am trying to run a docker container that takes the CONSUL_URL as an ENV Variable. For now, I have set up the consul on my localhost and I run it like this: `consul agent -dev -bind=127.0.0.1 -ui-dir /usr/local/Cellar/consul/0.7.0/share/consul/web-ui`

I am able to access the consul ui this way when I go to http://localhost:8500. But, now that I am running the docker container through this, `docker run -e CONSUL_URL=127.0.0.1:8500 -p 8500:8500 b321825a6c7a`, it gives me the following error:

```
2016/10/05 09:38:38 [ERR] (view) "key_or_default(foo.appconfig.properties/logger.name, "foo_PERF_LOG")" store key: error fetching: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/foo.appconfig.properties/logger.name?stale=&wait=60000ms: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused
2016/10/05 09:38:38 [ERR] (runner) watcher reported error: store key: error fetching: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/foo.appconfig.properties/logger.name?stale=&wait=60000ms: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused
Consul Template returned errors:
store key: error fetching: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/foo.appconfig.properties/logger.name?stale=&wait=60000ms: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refusedexecuting: 'myscript.sh run'
```

Why am I not able to connect with the consul URL? I also tried changing the localhost url to the IP Address of my machine, but, I get the same error with that too. I have done the port mapping, so, I guess it should work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: just to make sure, you are aware that the new docker "swarm mode" doesn't require Consul right?

Comment: @Alkaline, I did read about docker swarm but I am not sure if it also provides the functionality of changing the application configs from outside the docker container without having to rebuild the image all over again. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the --net=host flag.
This flag will create sockets for the exposed ports for all interfaces in the main OS.

```
docker run --net=host -e CONSUL_URL=127.0.0.1:8500  b321825a6c7a
```

Comment: it still shows the same error, i.e. getsockopt: connection refused.

Comment: Do you have any service running on this port?
check with "netstat -na | grep 8500"

Comment: This command shows `tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8500         *.*                    LISTEN`.

Comment: can  you please performed that command in the main OS before starting the container?

Comment: I am doing it in the main OS only. And this shows that I have the consul UI running on this port.

Comment: So that is the conflict i guess.You already have that tcp socket taken. When the new container tries to bind it self to that ip:port its not possible because its already in use. I have tested the command above and it works in an empty system. Can you test it in a different system?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Is there a possibility that I can run the consul ui on a different port and then try this? I think that should work. I am trying to mimic what happens in production environment, and hence, I have only my local system at my disposal.

Comment: I think I understand your problem fully now. You must stop the local consul in the main OS first. Aftter start the Consul container but you must activate the the ui inside the container. docker run --net=host b321825a6c7a agent -ui -server -bind=127.0.0.1